# preg_replace to strip out punctuation, white spaces and possessive forms of words?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace, string-formatting

```
$text =
"<tab><return><nbsp>O'Neil  really  
likes his pudding's, he really really does!!!1.5"
```

I would like to have this if possible where `'<tab>'` is an actual tab `\t` space not literally `'<tab>'`

```
$text = "O'Neil really likes his pudding he really really does 1.5"
```

*removing the whites paces and replaces them with one space, the punctuation, keeping the numbers or anything after apostrophe thats not a 's'.*

Thank you so much!

Comment: What about `O'Neil really likes his auntie's pudding, he really really does!`?

Comment: Why does the `1.5` keep its dot?

Comment: @Pekka, i'm trying to make an index of words and figures

Comment: ah, I see! Then it makes more sense. Although it'll break if the input is incorrect - many people tend to write `his aunties puddings`....

Comment: @Tim, because it's a decimal point and not a period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = trim(preg_replace(array('~[:;!?]|[.,](?![0-9])|\'s~', '~\s+~'), array('', ' '), $string));
```

That first gets rid of `'s` and then replaces multiple whitespace with one space. Eventually it removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: i guess this doesn't really remove commas or punctuation, but thank you!

Comment: Ooops, forgot that part. Now the regex should remove some punctuational characters and `.` and `,` if they are not followed by a digit.